# Returning all the grandson in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, has-many-through, grandchild

in my models, I have those relations:

- Category -> Subcategories : hasMany
- Subcategories -> Category : belongsTo
- Subcategory -> Products : hasMany
- Products -> Subcategory : belongsTo
- Category -> Products : hasManyThrough

I want to display all the products of a category through the subcategory table.

So, I wrote this code, but I have a problem at the dd($products), because only one products is got.

Could you please help me to fix the issue in my code ?

```
        public function show(Category $category)
        {
             $subcategories = Subcategory::join('categories','subcategories.category_id','categories.id')
            ->where('subcategories.category_id',$category->id)
            ->select('subcategories.id')
            ->get();
```

// dd($subcategories); give 3 different subcategories to me -> OK

```
            foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                $query = Product::where('products.subcategory_id',$subcategory->id)->get();
            }
            $products = $query;
```

// dd($products); give only 1 product to me (in fact, there are 4 products) -> NOK

```
            $data = [
                'title'=> $description = $category->title,
                'description'=> $description,
                'heading'=> config('app.name'),
                'category'=>$category,
                'subcategory'=>$subcategories,
                'products'=>$products,
            ];
            // dd($data);
            return view('category.show', $data)->with('products', $products);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are just redeclaring the $query variable instead of treating it as an array, that's why is just bringing one:

```html
 foreach ($subcategories as $subcategory) {
                $query[] = Product::where('products.subcategory_id',$subcategory->id)->get();
            }
            $products = $query;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alejandra, my dd is fine, but now, my view can't get the data with this code : {{ $product->title }}, what should I do ?

Comment: you are trying this? @foreach($products as $product)
       {{ $product->title}};
    @endforeach

Comment: Yes, not foreach but forelse/endForelse, that's likely the same.

Comment: error is 'Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.'

Comment: Another error is displayed : Undefined constant "title"

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant. Try accessing it as an array {{ $product[ 'title' ] }}

Comment: Undefined array key "title" : that is the new error message.

Comment: I would advice you to dd what $product is bringing to check what kind of data it is, even though for what I can see it should bring a collection. It could also mean that title is not in that table, hence, not in the collection instance.